# Test if point inside angle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

In 2D plane there are four points: `O`, `A`, `B`, `P`.

`O`, `A`, `B` define an "angle", i.e. two rays, both originating at `O`, and one passing though `A`, while the other goes through `B`. How to tell on which "side" of the angle the point `P` lies, i.e. whether it is inside the space marked by the two rays?

Note that the points are placed arbitrarily, i.e. the angle might have larger size than π.

This is similar problem to determining which side of line a point lies, as discussed e.g. in [comp.graphics.algorithms FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/) (Subject 1.02: How do I find the distance from a point to a line?), but here it is about two rays, instead of one line.

Edit: Apologies for not stating it more explicitly: the angle is oriented, i.e. given `P`, it might lay on the right of `O`, `A`, `B`, but then it is on the left of `O`, `B`, `A`. Let's say the triangle `O`, `A`, `B` has clock-wise orientation. Again, it is similar to the "which side of line" problem: there it also matters whether the line passes though `A`, `B`, or `B`, `A`.

An example:

```
        \                               \
         A                               B
          \   right                       \    left
   left    \                      right    \
            O------B----                    O------A----
```

Comment: If the angle can be larger than π, it is impossible to tell the inside from the outside.

Comment: @YvesDaoust See the edit, the angle is oriented.

Comment: @EcirHana: better like this. It would be even clearer to say "right/left of AOB".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion that follows is meant to detect points inside the hatched area.

[image]

There are two cases to be considered:

- the angle AOB is smaller than a flat, then the point P must be to the right of AO *and* to the right of OB (*intersection* of the two half planes),
- the angle AOB is larger than a flat, then the point P must be to the right of AO *or* to the right of OB (*union* of the two half planes).

The complete boolean expression is

AO|B . (AO|P . OB|P) + ¬ AO|B . (AO|P + OB|P),

where XY|Z expresses that Z lies on the right of XY, which is equivalent to "XYZ is clockwise" and is determined by the sign of the triangle area.

I don't think it is possible to make the expression simpler, unless you have several P for the same AOB.

Answer (score 4):

When looking from O, we can split the plane into two regions or "sides".

1. A region that sweeps ray OA towards ray OB while rotating counterclockwise.
2. And the rest, i.e. ray OB sweeps counterclockwise to OA.

To check if the point is in which region, you can use

```
// if isInRegion(O, A, B) is true, P is in the first region.
// otherwise, isInRegion(O, B, A) will be true.
bool isInRegion(O, A, B, P) {
    return isCCW(O, A, P) && !isCCW(O, B, P)
}

// ref: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/robust.html
// For more robust methods, see the link.
bool isCCW(a, b, c) {
    return ((a.x - c.x)*(b.y - c.y) - (a.y - c.y)*(b.x - c.x)) > 0;
}
```

[I tried it here.](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/hVVhb5swEP0rt0gr0FFCmlXbEnVSE21SpWmNukr7kPSDMU6xAjazTUjW9r/vDIGQLuuIZPDdu/O9x3F57AmSsd6o92PFDE16fo/K2O6XhaCGSwFcX4tb9oCP7o0PVz5MfJh58LgQgJdiplAWNJ3+3PnReXICb1pThV+I54VYiH4fI5YjSIzJR/1+WZYB1QHNioDFRf/thy+/CrJifSWjQpsgMVm6EJ1KbEbiQ+QDbSvAlN8nI7iTQBNGV2ASBlJxJgypouQShpBLLoz22wgL0vxBgE5kkcYQMaxrzZRmMSRMMR9aqOaCMuACY7gGKqWKuSAG47fasAy2wDaGiVhDLEtREhXroA2+NlDyNAUhDWTEGKZgKRXIQkFeqFxqVh2HuWXxkGDcwuwUdV0SbOAMaLDxTt0o2FbPWw9v6Gl21tOgPPgM4XgntP21wsWKlDMrHE2VD2ZjWvHWBAuBSxCshBkxSTDliqbMYofeuMbkwRIpTGWKhV/aFPD0BE6UErpyxvs0pkljpb5DTVwC72A+CH0YhPdeDTQBlQLVsmCsY9xYuyfsUz+/4HDbvPwdDX3AI/pKbLg91Y3OiAeneDBe439Q/cZFRdTG7blqo+SKvcq2lXNnrmuZtyRrf7fO+eDeO0Kn/qqkDzWtvIo44ERqTtJyImfSC4RUGUn5b+ZW3LzxX/xlzf91bN7B5v/DdkRz90Jlcs3upCv3lhQFRQs50JMoijZ73kulaYrt/yLpkU6zR1cmNwwGPoTBJ7ucX1Sr1/S7LfSm24HueYidh4tXO68OnMMLdL5vfJMD30cbNxh6TdpZ1xsoImKZuba7hmFoMXVn1rPPMRI/c4ktMXducHWuHPvmWwjOQidmLNerbZQWbI+btLiZO8O9TPma4TayzplTFcOX4B6fxm3PdNqq40aNgKU4a46iJrupXSmJfwCRYmRVD8zeaH7//Ac=)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does report the same side of `O`, `A`, `B` and `O`, `B`, `A`. I would like to distinguish those two case as well.